# ADF - Incremental Load

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a question regarding copy activity and incremental load. The idea is to pull cdc logs from CDC table incrmentally but the source table is badly designed and does not have any primary key column npr timestamp column to increment on so with copy activity I am not sure how to perform incremental loads. Has anyone had similar situation? The table is on-prem sql server so data flow as far as I know does not support self hosted IR.

Thanks!

Comment: can you alter the schema of the source table?

Comment: @PratikLad It will be a hassle to change it which is why I resorted to see if there is something else. It is really big table so adding primary key or something is pain in the neck + other team is maintaining it which makes it a bit time consuming.

Comment: Then AFAIK the only possible way is you need to full load the database every time as we can't segregate the data as new and older

Comment: @PratikLad that is what I thought so

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have any watermark column or primary key on your table, so you need to apply below three step solution. you can also refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-tracking-feature-portal)

1. **Initial loading of historical data**
2. **Enable change tracking technology in the source database**
3. **Incremental loading of delta data on a schedule**

**Initial loading of historical data**:

You create a pipeline with a copy activity that copies the entire data from the source data store (On-prem SQL) to the destination data store

[image]

**Enable change tracking technology in the source database**

> - Enable change tracking technology in the source database in Azure SQL Database.
>
>   ```sql
>   ALTER DATABASE <your database name>
>   SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
>   (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)  
>   ALTER TABLE data_source_table
>   ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
>   WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
>   ```
> - Create a new table and store called  `ChangeTracking_version`  with a default value by running the following query:
>
>   ```sql
>   create table table_store_ChangeTracking_version
>      (
>      TableName varchar(255),
>      SYS_CHANGE_VERSION BIGINT,
>       );
>       DECLARE @ChangeTracking_version BIGINT
>       SET @ChangeTracking_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();  
>       INSERT INTO table_store_ChangeTracking_version
>       VALUES ('data_source_table', @ChangeTracking_version)
>   ```
> - Run the following query to create a stored procedure in your database. The pipeline invokes this stored procedure to update the change tracking version in the table that you created in the previous step.
>
>   ```sql
>        CREATE PROCEDURE Update_ChangeTracking_Version
>        @CurrentTrackingVersion BIGINT, @TableName varchar(50)
>            AS
>            BEGIN
>            UPDATE table_store_ChangeTracking_version
>            SET [SYS_CHANGE_VERSION] = @CurrentTrackingVersion
>            WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
>            END
>   ```

**Incremental loading of delta data on a schedule**:

You build a pipeline and execute it on a regular basis with the following actions inside:

1. To obtain the old and new `SYS_CHANGE_VERSION` values from the Azure SQL Database, create *two lookup activities*.
2. To transfer the data that has been added, changed, or removed (the delta data) between two `SYS_CHANGE_VERSION` values from a source to destination, create *one copy activity*.
3. In order to change the value of `SYS_CHANGE_VERSION` for the subsequent pipeline run, create *one stored procedure activity*.

[image]